# Is there a program to check the list of root CAs in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, security, ssl, certificate

Motivated by [this](https://superuser.com/questions/727129/what-trusted-root-certification-authorities-should-i-trust?rq=1) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/734110/is-it-safe-to-add-an-untrusted-certificate-to-trusted-root-certification-authori) question, I'd like to ask if there is a way to check if additional certificates have been maliciously added to the list of root CAs of Firefox. Possible ways could be:

- an add-on/extension that reviews the list
- a way to export all the trusted certificates from within Firefox, and an external program/website where I can upload the list and check it for extra ones.

I would run this verification both on my personal machine and on machines administered by others. I am well aware that a sysadmin could circumvent these checks by installing a recompiled version of Firefox, and that the root CA system is way beyond broken in many other ways, but at least it's a first step.

Comment: You forget the system admin can install any certificate they want.  If you are not the admin even if you find a non-trust worthy certificate not much you can do about it

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I realize that they can install any certificate. I'd like a way to check if this has happened (even if it can be circumvented, but that requires more work and "raises the bar").

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Certutil` utility to list all [Non-Default Root Certificate Settings](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA:UserCertDB#Listing_All_Non-Default_Root_Certificate_Settings).

Its a commandline tool, read more about it here: [Windows](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732443.aspx) & [Unix](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_Security_Services).

The instructions below on how to run it against your Firefox Certificate Database and it's other uses can be found [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA:UserCertDB).

The section on the Mozilla Wiki says the following:

> There is currently no UI to list all built-in root certificates for 
>   which you have overridden the default trust settings You can use the
>   certutil tool to list all the certificates in your personal database,
>   which includes built-in root certificates whose trust you have changed
>   along with added root certificates and many other kinds of
>   certificates.
>
> Run this command (doing it while the Mozilla application is running is
>   probably unsupported but does not seem to cause problems in practice):
>
> `certutil -d PROFILE_DIR -L`

There is also a bug report to add the feature you are looking for:

[Bug 545498 - Provide Capabilities to Detect and Manage Root Certificate Inconsistencies](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=545498)

In the meantime however, you could use the tool to extract your settings and compare your certificates against the [list of CA certificates](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/governance/policies/security-group/certs/included/) that are distributed with Mozilla software products, available in a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Ah-tHXMAwqU3dGx0cGFObG9QM192NFM4UWNBMlBaekE&single=true&gid=1&output=html) or [text file](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt).